# Why am I getting an error loading resources/resources.xaml in the designer when I instantiate my WPF user control on a page?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I only get this error in the designer; my game runs just fine.

The error is "Cannot locate resource resources/resources.xaml". It only occurs on views where I reference my user control, and only in the designer - not when I design the user control itself, and not at runtime; I'm able to compile my game just fine even though I have this error.

Here is where I declare my user control instance:

`<local:StatsView Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="stats"/>`

And here are the relevant parts of my user control:

`<UserControl x:Class="Wormholes.Views.StatsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wormholes.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Resources.xaml" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>`

I'm also referencing this same Resources.xaml in each of my pages, in addition to from the user control; could this be causing the error? If so, how do I work around it?

Answer (score 0):

You have used a Relative URI, so it will looks for your resource file in a somewhere that you used your UserControl. It can't find you resource file because your resource file is not in the AbsolutePath.

AbsolutePath = CurrentPath (r.g Where you used your UserControl) + RelativePath

so Use an AbsolutePath:

```
   <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/{YourAssemblyName};component/Resources/Resources.xaml" />
```